# I am getting a error on my vba code - method open of object connection failed- run time error - 2147467259

Tags: excel, vba

My excel has recently been updated to the office 365 version.

I have pasted the code I am using below -

```
 Sub sbADOExample()

   Dim sSQLQry As String
   Dim ReturnArray
   Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
   Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String

   Dim MyFolder As String
   Dim MyFile As String
   MyFolder = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
   MyFile = Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FTE Updates").Range("E12")
   MySheet = "Report"

   DBPath = MyFolder & "\" & MyFile

   Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile

   sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DBPath _
   & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

   Conn.Open sconnect
```

Conn.Open sconnect- this is the line where the error is occuring.

Comment: Maybe `";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'"`? Try this [link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/) for further details.

Comment: What os the extensiton of the excel file that you are trying to open? Try changing `8.0` to `12.0`

Comment: the excel file im trying to open is a microsoft excel workbook so xlsx. I have tried to change it from 8.0 to 12.0 and still am getting the same error